# Angular form field - how to invalidate

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement mat-error triggered from the code.
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field
    appearance="outline"
    class="awa-primary-input-40"
    <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
    <input
        type="number"
        [formControl]="formControl"
        matInput
        [min]="1"
        [max]="11"
     />
    <mat-error>
        Test Error
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Control creation:

```
formControl: [
   1,
   {
       validators: [Validators.min(1), Validators.max(10)],
       updateOn: 'blur',
   },
]
```

When I enter 11 into the field I get the error shown.
But what I want is to invalidate the field based on some condition.
Any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you'll find this useful: [Angular Custom Form Validators: Complete Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-validators/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add custom validator to FormControl https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators

or set errors to formControl directly by calling setErrors method

```
formControl.setErrors({myError: 'reason'})
```

This method is rarely used and usually signals that you are doing something completely wrong.

Btw, display `mat-error` only when there is error condition

```
<mat-error *ngIf="formControl.hasError('myError')> 
  Message {{formControl.getError('myError')}} 
</mat-error>
```

Btw, `min` `max` attributes are redundant if validators are added to `formControl`

Comment: Dont think I need a condition to when to show the error. It is only shown when a field fails its validation.